# OnActivityResult Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android-activity, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Problem: I need to access and override OnActivityResult for the current Xamarin.Forms.Context.

Issues: I don't know how to do this.

What I tried: I tried extending Activity, but I get a null Exception. I tried creating a `BaseActivity : Activity` but I don't know how to pass the result and I still get a null Exception.

my class looks something like this:

```
public class Media : IMedia
{
        Activity context;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the class.
        /// </summary>
        public Media()
        {
            context = Forms.Context as Activity;

            //Check for Camera intent
            takePictureIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            //context.StartActivityForResult (takePictureIntent, 0);

            //Check for gallery intent
            pickPictureIntent = new Intent();
            pickPictureIntent.SetType ("image/*");
            pickPictureIntent.SetAction (Intent.ActionGetContent);
            //context.StartActivityForResult (Intent.CreateChooser(Intent, "Select Picture"), 1);

            if (context.PackageManager.HasSystemFeature (PackageManager.FeatureCamera)) {
                IsCameraAvailable = true;
                IsPhotosSupported = true;
                IsVideosSupported = true;
            }

        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case 0:
                if (resultCode == Result.Ok) {
                    var selectedImage = data.Data;
                    //imageview.setImageUri(selectedImage);
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (resultCode == Result.Ok) {
                    var selectedImage = data.Data;
                    //imageview.setImageUri(selectedImage);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form.Context is same as your MainActivity.
You should override your MainActivity.OnActivityResult instead.